# What is the output of tf.split?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, tensor

So assuming I have this:

> TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(32)])

And I use tf.split on this tensor _X with the dimension above:

```
_X = tf.split(_X, 128, 0)
```

What is the shape of this new tensor? The output is a list so its hard to know the shape of this new tensor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tf.split() returns the list of tensor objects. You could know shape of each tensor object as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.random_uniform([256, 32]);
Y = tf.split(X,128,0)
Y_shape = tf.shape(Y[1])

sess = tf.Session()
X_v,Y_v,Y_shape_v = sess.run([X,Y,Y_shape]) 
# numpy style
print X_v.shape
print len(Y_v)
print Y_v[100].shape
# TF style
print len(Y)
print Y_shape_v
```

Output :

```
(256, 32)
128
(2, 32)
128
[ 2 32]
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 9):

`tf.split(X, row = n, column = m)` is used to split the data set of the variable into `n` number of pieces row wise and `m` numbers of pieces column wise.

For example, we have data_set `x` of size `(10,10)`, 
then `tf.split(x, 2, 0)` will break the data_set of `x` in 2 set of size `(5, 10)`

but if we take `tf.split(x, 2, 2)`,
then we will get 4 sets of data of size `(5, 5)`.

Comment: What about the _order_ of elements?  For example, if the original axis 0 contains [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], then after `split(x,2,0)` would it become [1,2,3,4,5] and [6,7,8,9,10] _or_ [1,3,5,7,9] and [2,4,6,8,10]?  No one seems to even care to ask this??

Answer (score -1):

The new version of tensorflow defines split function as follows:

tf.split(
    value,
    num_or_size_splits,
    axis=0,
    num=None,
    name='split'
)

however, when I try to run it in R:

```
X = tf$random_uniform(minval=0,
                      maxval=10,shape(256, 32),name = "X");

Y = tf$split(X,num_or_size_splits = 2,axis = 0)
```

it reports error message:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Rank-0 tensors are not supported as the num_or_size_splits argument to split. Argument provided: 2.0
```